# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file error in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

While debugging an Angular js application in webStorm IDE the following error occurs

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/../list.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Javascript code :

```
var amailServices = angular.module('Amail',['ngRoute']);
function emailRouteConfig($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        controller: ListController,
        templateUrl : 'list.html'}).

    when('/view/:id',{
        controller : DetailsController,
        templateUrl:'detail.html'}).

    otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });
}
amailServices.config(emailRouteConfig);
```

How to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a fix in web storm IDE .

I changed the server to `http://localhost:63342/`

Now it works fine in debugging