# Getting 404 not found error for angular js in eclipse with apache tomcat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

Check for the code in plunker
  Able to open in fire fox, but in google chrome getting error
  1.`XMLHttpRequest` cannot load       `file:///C:/Users/sg0222361/Desktop/Hi/pages/login.html`. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

2.In eclipse with tomcat getting error 404 error.

Comment: Plunker Site http://plnkr.co/edit/w63uf9YYJ39HZ0BbV7OI?p=preview

Comment: possible duplicate of (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht         (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210843/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-error-in-angular-js

Comment: No issues with webstrom..but why not in eclipse with apache tomcat